# Returning svg image back to main activity

Tags: android, svg

I am using SVGs in my android app.
I created a `GridView` for displaying the SVGs, but I don't know how to return the selected `svg` to the main activity to make it visible to the user.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `startActivityForResult()`.  Read the section named "Starting Activities and Getting Results" here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

So your main activity will start your "Select an SVG" activity, and that will return a result back to your main activity.